# Remove part of an .xml file in console

Tags: xml, bash, replace, sed, console

I'm trying to recursively find all files that match the pattern *.xml and remove some code inside them.

This is what I have came up with:

- find all .xml files and remove lines
- from the first occurence of `def=something` to first occurence of `</box>`

```
find config/view -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sed -n '/def=something/,/<\/box>/!p' > tmp.xml {} \; -exec mv tmp.xml {} \;
```

It works fine for 1 file in directory but it gives:

```
mv: cannot access tmp.xml
```

when I invoke it on directories containing many files

Where's the bug in my script? Or maybe there is a better/simpler way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is that in the `-exec sed` statement of `find`, you're *not* executing:

```
sed -n '/def=something/,/</box>/!p' > tmp.xml {}
```

(with the redirection).

In fact, your line is equivalent to:

```
find config/view -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sed -n '/def=something/,/<\/box>/!p' {} \; -exec mv tmp.xml {} \; > tmp.xml
```

that is, it's all the output of `find` that is redirected to the file `tmp.xml`. Then, after the first file is found, tmp.xml doesn't exist anymore (as it has been moved) and everything is screwed up!

To fix that, you can either use inline editing, as shown in fedorqui's answer:

```
find config/view -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sed -i -n '/def=something/,/<\/box>/!p' {} +
```

(notice the `+` at the end of the line), or you could:

```
find config/view -type f -name "*.xml" -exec bash -c 'sed -n "/def=something/,/<\/box>/!p" "$0" > tmp.xml; mv tmp.xml "$0"' {} \;
```

but that is not as good. It's useful though, in case your `sed` doesn't support the `-i` flag (GNU `sed` does).

Comment: btw -in is bad and doubles the lines in files the option should be -i -n

Answer (score 2):

`>` is  a shell construct, and cannot be used with the `-exec` primary; its arguments are passed directly to one of the system calls in the `exec` family, not processed by the shell. `find` is treating the `>` and `tmp.xml` as just two more string arguments to pass to `sed`, not a redirection, and so `tmp.xml` is never created.

One option is to explicitly start a shell for each file:

```
find config/view -type f -name "*.xml" -exec \
  sh -c "sed -in '/def=something/,/<\/box>/!p' {} > tmp.xml && mv tmp.xml {}"
```

Another, as fedorqui suggested, is to let `sed` handle the atomic file operation itself with the `-i` option (note that the usage of `-i` varies slightly between implentations; check your `sed` man page for details).

Comment: `{}` is not to be used like this!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes I see I was adding {} because there was error after > without {} it was hanging